# How to preserve order of list after applying flatMap() to it?

Tags: java, rx-java

The call to api.bookings returns a list of bookings in a predefined order. The call to api.order() returns a booking but with some extra info. After applying flatMap() the order of the bookings list gets messed up. (bookings.toList() is just a list if Bookings). How can I get the values in the zip function in the order as emitted by  .from(bookings.toList()). Note: I can't use toSortedList as I have no way to compare two bookings.

```
bookingsSubscription = api.bookings()
                    .flatMap(bookings -> 
                        Observable.zip(
                            Observable 
                                .from(bookings.toList()) 
                                .flatMap(booking -> api.order(booking.orderId)),

                            Observable.from(bookings.toList()),

                            (newBooking, oldBooking) -> {
                               // at this point newBooking != oldBooking
                            }
                    ).toList())
                    .subscribe(callback);
```

api.order

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`concatMap` will work but won't give the concurrency which you want. `concatMapEager` on the other hand will.

An equivalent option is to create a `List<Observable>` manually and use `Observable.zip(Iterable, FuncN)` to combine the list. This will have the same effect as `concatMapEager`.

See [RxJava issue 3017](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/issues/3017) for a discussion.

Comment: Thanks. It's kind of weird documentation of concatMapEager hints order but documentation of, say, flatMapSingle (my case) that works on items emitted by Observable.from (iterable) - tells nothing. Easy to mistake.

Comment: Nice explanation here: https://nurkiewicz.com/2017/08/flatmap-vs-concatmap-vs-concatmapeager.html

Answer (score 5):

Use `.concatMap` instead of `.flatMap`

http://fernandocejas.com/2015/01/11/rxjava-observable-tranformation-concatmap-vs-flatmap/

Answer (score 0):

Is `api.bookings()` return an hot or cold observable ? I think it's a cold in your case due to the issue you've encounter. As it's a cold observable, the bookings sequence is executed twice (and the states is not shared between all subscriptions performed by the zip operator)

First, you can code can be simplier so easier to understand. You can remove `.toList()` method calls as you perform an `Observable.from` which 'flatten' your list.

```
bookingsSubscription = api.bookings()
                .flatMap(coldBookings -> {
                    ConnectableObservable bookings = coldBooking.publish(); 
                    Observable zip = Observable.zip(
                        bookings.flatMap(booking -> api.order(booking.orderId)),
                        bookings,
                        (newBooking, oldBooking) -> {
                           // ...
                    });
                    bookings.connect();
                    return zip.toList();
                })
                .subscribe(callback);
```

What I have done : remove useless `Observable.from(obs.toList())` and using directly the observable.
Converting the cold observable to an hot observable using `publish/connect` methods

You can get more information on hot/cold observable here : http://www.introtorx.com/content/v1.0.10621.0/14_HotAndColdObservables.html